# CSS Transitions Error

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am having a few problems with CSS. I have scripted a simple text box, that when it is clicked a div drops down, but it does not seem to be working. If anyone could help me, I'll be greatfull.

**CSS:**

```
input {
    top:18px;
    left:20px;
    width:1230px;
    padding:4px;
    border:1px dashed #eeeeee;
    font:16px arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#d8d8d8;
}

input:focus {
    height:200px;
}

div {
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0;
    margin:0; 
    height:0; 
    width:1230px; 
    border:1px dashed #eeeeee; 
    background-color:transparent; 
    transition:height.5s; 
    -moz-transition:height 0.5s;
    -o-transition:height 0.5s; 
    -webkit-transition:height 0.5s;
}

body {
    background-image:url('pic.bmp');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: There must be javascript involved, if some action occurs on click.  It would help to see the javascript/HTML.

Comment: @Mash, No I'm using CSS Transitions.

Comment: @Mash Why must there be JavaScript involved? I'm sure he's referring to :focus pseudo-selector.

Comment: could you show us some html as well, perhaps even a fiddle. I think you are looking for input:focus + div as the selector for your transition, but hard to tell... Something like this perhaps? http://jsfiddle.net/xLPxv/

Comment: btw, noticed the .bmp as background image. Bad idea, use a compacter format like .jpeg or .png, but that has nothing to do with problem offcourse

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you need to change `input:focus` to `input:focus div` (if the div is in the input element), or something like `input:focus + div` (if the div is after the input), but without seeing your markup it's hard to say.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `input:focus + div` to select your division.

Here is the Pure CSS version of what you want : [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xtL7h/)

Answer (score 0):

The div has `overflow: hidden` property, which will cause any inner elements' heights to be ignored in the rendering of the div's height.